# Time based resource availability

Tags: java, performance

I'm currently working on a module for a system that handles event scheduling.  Each event object has a start and end timestamp and an array of required resources.  Each resource has a limited number available and there is a limit on the number of events that can happen concurrently.  Ultimately it's similar to a meeting room booking type system where there are a finite number of rooms, projectors, chairs etc.

At the moment, I'm looping through the current events to calculate resource utilization and concurrent event count, however when this runs to thousands of events it seems like an inefficient way to do it.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1):

This is an so called [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problem. Finding a ... say 'mathematically optimal' solution can become very expensive as your sample size grows. The time you spend on a ... say 'real world' solution depends on your requirements. Less optimal solutions can be found by using some heuristics.

**One heuristic:**

You could sort your modules by some metric. Than add them in decreasing order to your pool. Starting with the most expensive modules. Add all modules that also fit into the same slot. After that open a new slot for the remaining modules. And so forth.